# Why are my asynchron functions not running really asynchronously (in paralell) in my Blazor Server app?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, blazor, blazor-server-side

I am normaly a senior PLC Programmer, but also now programming a Blazor server app. I know it is shamefull to post this question, after lot of questions about asynchron programming (async-await) in C# have been posted. It is also Ok for me if you close this question due to this reason. But I have really read tens of posts in stackoverflow, and in the rest of the internet but still cannot understand how async / await is working. It is always explained that this is the easiest method for asynchron programming. But my old brain cannot understand. I thought, perhaps a patient developer can help me nevertheless and explaine me the mechanism with very easy words.

What I want to do is quite simple:
I have a page in my Blazor server app, where the user is selecting a Machine from a dropdown list. After selection is done, he has to click to the "Connect" button. When this button is pressed

a) The dropdown list shall be deactivated immediatly (This part I have programmed as first)

b) a simple ping test shall be carried out, in order to know whether machine is available or not.(This part I have programmed as second.)

--> At the end a ping status text shall be displayed on screen.

Of course I want that these two actions shall be done asynchronously.
But after days of lots of trials, I have the shamefull status that, always the ping is carried out first and the program is blocked for 3-4 seconds when the machine is not reachable (no ping answer), and finally the dropdown box is being deactivated always afterwards.

I know that PLC programming and C# are quite different worlds.
Either I should really give up the C# programming and think about retirement with my PLC history. Or someone should explain me what is wrong in my code and correct my code if possible. I have really red as I said lots of entries but, each time I get more and more confused.
This is my code:

```
@page "/connect"
@using System.IO
@using System.Net.NetworkInformation;

<select value="@selectedString_MAE" class="MAE" disabled="@IsDisabled" @onchange="func_MAE">
<option value="">-- Select MAE --</option>
@foreach (var mae in templates_MAE)
{
    <option value=@mae>@mae</option>
}
</select>
<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="@(() => { paralell_tasks(); })">Connect</button>
<p>Ping: @Ping_Win_status</p>
<p>Ping: @Ping_Win_response</p>

@code {

public static bool IsDisabled { get; set; }

public static async void paralell_tasks()
{       
    Disable_DropDown(); // Why is that part not processes as first ??? Please explain me??
    await Ping_Test_Win(); //Why is this part blocking my code always when machine is offline??
}

public static void Disable_DropDown()
{
    IsDisabled = true;
}

public static async Task Ping_Test_Win()
{
        Ping_Win_response = "";
        Ping_Win_status = "";
        try
        {
            Ping Ping_Win = new Ping();              
            PingReply Reply_win = Ping_Win.Send(Connect2.MAE_IP_Win, 4000);
            if (Reply_win != null)
            {
                Ping_Win_response = "Win " + Reply_win.Status + "   Time(ms) : " + Reply_win.RoundtripTime.ToString() + "   Address : " + Reply_win.Address;
                Ping_Win_status = Reply_win.Status.ToString();

                if (Ping_Win_status.Contains("Success"))
                {
                    //Some code
                }
            }
            if (Reply_win == null)
            {
                Ping_Win_response = "Win Null TimedOut";
                Ping_Win_status = "";
            }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Error logging code
        }
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: Async methods should return `Task` not `void`, and the onclick lambda should be `"@(async () => ...)"`

Comment: @Pluriscient [According to the docs, async event handlers can return void.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/async-return-types)

Comment: @AKX consider me corrected ;)

Comment: @Mdarende, the value of the `@onclick` directive should be `paralell_tasks`,  the name of the method you want to call, not the lambda expression: `@(() => { paralell_tasks(); })`

Comment: @Mdarende, have you not been told to stop using static methods ? I rememeber you were told...

Comment: `Why is that part not processes as first ?` Because you have to use `async Task paralell_tasks`, instead of `async void paralell_tasks`

Comment: `Either I should really give up the C# programming` Please, don't despair. Learning is good for you. At least you get some income, no ? I've never made a penny from programming.

Comment: @enet I stand corrected there then :)

Comment: Avoid `static`. Also avoid `async void`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're under the misconception that when you call `Disbable_Dropdown` a render event will take place.  It doesn't because the whole code block is synchronous and the Renderer, which actually does the re-render only gets some thread time once `parelell_tasks` had completed.  So the ping finishes and finally the UI gets updated.

Here's an all in one page that demonstrates how to do what I think you are expecting. "environment.gov.ck" is a long way away down a lot of wire so relatively slow and shows the pings happening.

```
@page "/"
@using System.Text
@using System.IO
@using System.Net.NetworkInformation;

<h3>Ping</h3>

<select class="input-select" value="@ipAddress" disabled="@this.DisableSelect" @onchange=IpAddressSelected>
    <option value="">-- Select a Machine --</option>
    <option value="environment.gov.ck">environment.gov.ck</option>
    <option value="www.coldelm.com">www.coldelm.com</option>
    <option value="www.microsoft.com">www.microsoft.com</option>
</select>

<div class="m-2">
    <button class="btn btn-success" disabled="@this.DisableButton" @onclick=this.PingAddress>Ping @ipAddress</button>
</div>

<div>
    <pre>
        @this.log.ToString()
    </pre>
</div>

@code {
    private StringBuilder log = new StringBuilder();
    private string ipAddress = string.Empty;
    private bool DisableSelect = false;
    private bool DisableButton = true;

    private void IpAddressSelected(ChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Value is not null)
        {
            this.ipAddress = e.Value?.ToString() ?? string.Empty;
            this.DisableButton = false;
        }
    }

    private async Task PingAddress()
    {
        this.DisableSelect = true;
        // Do a yield to let the Renderer run it's first re-render
        await Task.Delay(1);
        if (this.ipAddress != string.Empty)
            await PingMachine();
    }

    private async ValueTask PingMachine(int timesToPing = 4)
    {
        log.AppendLine($"Pinging {this.ipAddress}");
        // make sure the UI gets updated 
        // we may have already used the first yield render event in the caller so make sure it happens
        StateHasChanged();
        await Task.Delay(1);
        // StateHasChanged will get run by UI event Handler on the first await, 
        // after that we need to call it manually
        var counter = 1;
        while (counter <= timesToPing)
        {
            var reply = await Pinger(this.ipAddress);
            log.AppendLine($"Pinged {this.ipAddress} : {counter} times => address: {reply.Address} - time:{reply.RoundtripTime} - status: {reply.Status.ToString()}");
            counter++;
            // Manually call as we need to update the UI with the new message
            // The render will only actual happen when we get a yield when we await in the next iteration of the loop
            StateHasChanged();
        }

        this.DisableButton = true;
        this.ipAddress = string.Empty;
        this.DisableSelect = false;
        // StateHasChanged will get run by UI event Handler when it gets a completed Task
    }

    private async ValueTask<PingReply> Pinger(string ipAddress)
    {
        var ping = new Ping();
        var reply = await ping.SendPingAsync(ipAddress);
        return reply;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi MrC aka Shaun Curtis

Comment: Hi MrC aka Shaun Curtis I have tried your code 1:1, But you have disabled the select box, directly after selecting a value. I mean this is not excactly what I want to do. I would disable the select box, just when the ping button is pressed. So the two tasks 1) disable select box" and 2) Ping Async should be in paralell. I mean if this is not possible in Blazor I will not insist. I just wanted to know if its possible

Comment: Yes, see my revised code.  Note the use of `await Task.Delay(1);`.  This yields to the caller.  As this is the first yield in the UI event, it will call `StateHasChanged()' and also yield, giving the Renderer time to run any stacked Render Events.  There's a Gist here that explains why and how components re-render - https://gist.github.com/ShaunCurtis/7473e475e1a3010f02b0ea4536c54acd

Comment: Absolutely working now as expected. You are great! Thank you for your patient. I have learnt a lot with this simple example!!!

Answer (score 3):

A function being [`async`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/async) doesn't make it asynchronous if it doesn't [`await`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/await) for anything to yield control to other code. (It might be worth to (re-)read [the async/await concept guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/).)

To make that function actually async, you would need to use [`Ping.PingAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.networkinformation.ping.sendasync?view=net-6.0) and then wait until the callback happens. (I should note `PingAsync` isn't async in the `async`/`await` ([TAP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/task-asynchronous-programming-model)) sense, but in the sense that it doesn't block and causes a callback to fire later, so you can't just `await` on it, but you could [wrap it in a Task of your own](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskfactory-1.startnew?view=net-6.0).)

If you need to run a synchronous function asynchronously, you could run it in a different thread, using e.g. the [built-in thread pool stuff](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadpool.queueuserworkitem?view=net-6.0).

Comment: Yes, you could use "thread pool stuff" but only because Ping() implies this is Blazor Server-side. For similar problems with Blazor Wasm that is not an option.

Answer (score 1):

I can fix the first issue for you.
First, simplify the calling code

```html
  ... @onclick="paralell_tasks">
```

then make `paralell_tasks()` actually async for UI purposes:

```cs
//public static async void paralell_tasks()
  private async Task paralell_tasks()
  {       
    Disable_DropDown();   // Q: Why is that part not processes as first ??? 
    // A: it is processed first but not yet rendered
    await Task.Delay(1);  // render the updates so far
    await Ping_Test_Win(); //Why is this part blocking my code always when machine is offline??
  }
```

that leaves `//Why is this part blocking my code always when machine is offline??`

And the answer is that your `Ping_Test_Win()` may be `async` but it is not asynchronous, it does not `await` anywhere. Rewrite it based on PingAsync() as @AKX points out.

Comment: Thank you so much "await Task.Delay(1);" was one critical point here, and also the PingAsync. I brought my code to work now. Have learnt a lot with your support. Thanks again!!!